# Invalid object name #temp after switching from JTDS to JDBC driver

Tags: java, jdbc, azure-sql-database, jtds

I switched from JTDS 1.3 to Microsoft's JDBC driver. I changed none of my code but am now getting the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid object name '#temp'. Query:  

CREATE TABLE #temp ( 
[Server] [varchar](100) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT NOT NULL, 
[ServiceName] [varchar](200) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT NOT NULL, 
[Type] [varchar](100) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT NOT NULL, 
[ThreadId] [int] NOT NULL, 
[WarningDetails] NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL ) 

INSERT INTO #temp ([Server], [ServiceName], [Type], [ThreadId], [WarningDetails]) VALUES ('10.0.1.5', 'ServiceProcessing', 'mainServiceThread', 0, '') 
INSERT INTO #temp ([Server], [ServiceName], [Type], [ThreadId], [WarningDetails]) VALUES ('10.0.1.5', 'ServiceProcessing', 'Controller', 1, '')
```

I verified my permissions are working because i'm using the same login and can successfully run this query in SSMS. I am using Azure SQL.

Comment: It may be using a different style of sending parameters. What happens if you quote like this: `\`temp\``?

Comment: Thanks @chrylis. Those are back ticks, not single quotes, right? I'll give it a shot.

Comment: I meant to include the `#` there, sorry. Yes, backticks. I'm not a SQL expert by any means, but this is one trick that I know from Postgres and I think is standard(ish).

Comment: @chrylis Backticks are entirely non-standard and only MySQL/MariaDB use it. The SQL standard quote character is `"`, while SQL Server defaults to `[` and `]`. And in any case, it is not necessary to quote it, because `#` is syntactically valid in SQL Server and signifies a temporary table.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] and the full exception stacktrace.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks! Unfortunately, I've found that `"` doesn't work for names in some engines... one more reason I don't pretend to be a SQL expert.

Comment: Please include your Java code.  If you create a temp table in a nested batch, it won't have session lifetime.  So it's critically important how the CREATE TABLE query is sent to the server.  see eg https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/67b10d74-e94f-4b58-8ee3-59ff390db1cf/jdbc-and-temp-tables